# How can I center text inside a div with the same space to the left and right?

Tags: html, css

I have an H1 element inside a DIV inside a header:

```
<header class="container_12">
   <div class="grid_3">
       <h1><b>xx</b></h1>
   </div>
</header>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.container_12 .grid_3 {
    width: 23%;
}
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.99%;
    margin-right: 0.99%;
}
header h1 {
    margin:0 auto; 
text-align:center;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 77px;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI Web Light", "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI Web Regular", "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
}
```

I am looking for some advice. I would like to position the "xx" text in the middle of the grid_3 with the same 
amount of space to the left right and left of the "xx".

Comment: The problem is that you have `display:inline;` on your h1. http://jsfiddle.net/cKMzj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
text-align:center;
```

Should do the trick, applied to the h1.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qGaCY/1/

Comment: That didn't change it for me. I posted my header h1 css.

Comment: No need for the `margin:0 auto;`, my lover.

Comment: Ah, it works fine in the fiddle. Edited, thanks you wonderful Englishman! Try it now @Melina

Answer (score 2):

```
.grid_3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**NOTE**: `<b>..</b>` is deprecated in HTML5. Use `<strong>..</strong>` instead.

Comment: Actually, `<b>..</b>` *isn't* deprecated. Unless the HTML5 specification has been updated to say so since I last looked through it, nowhere does it mention *not* to use `<b>`.

Edit: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element

Melina is misusing the tag here, but it isn't deprecated.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for this reference. I was confused when using Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah it was Bootstrap that first put me under the impression it was deprecated, too. It may actually have been listed as deprecated when the HTML5 specification was first written up, but who knows!

Answer (score 2):

You can either do:

1. `text-align: center;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-align

1. `margin: 0 auto;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin

```
 .container_12 .grid_3 {
    width: 23%;
 }

 .container_12 > .grid_3 > h1 {
    text-align: center
 }
```

A jsfiddle for your current example: http://jsfiddle.net/bxG27/

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 77px;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI Web Light", "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI Web Regular", "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKMzj/). I've given the heading a dark background so you can easily see that the text is centrally aligned.
As I mentioned in my comment on your post, `display:inline;` on your h1 is what's causing it to fail for you, as widths are not applied to inline elements.